# Button opens wrong menu

Tags: java, android

I am currently making a program which opens a menu with a traditional menu button. There two different buttons: first should open the left side menu and the second is made for opening settings. The problem is both these buttons open the same menu. Please help me to make things so that each button opens its own menu.

I've made the main part of the app with a youtube video about these buttons. But there is a problem with them.

The following is the snapshot of menu that is opened with left side button:

[image: Menu that opens left side button]

And the following is the look of the app

[image: The look of the app]

And the following is the snapshot of the same menu opened with second button

[image: The second button opens the same menu]

Here is my code:

```
package com.danielliakhovetskyi.mainactivity;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Menu menu;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    MenuItem maths;
    private boolean menuItemsAssigned = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable
                (Color.parseColor("#872be3"))); //making ActionBar light-coloured
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);


        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navview);
        navigationView.setItemTextAppearance(R.style.WithFont);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Default is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu);
       /* this.menu = menu;

        maths = menu.findItem(R.id.maths);
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.INFO, "Maths Clicked");
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + maths, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        maths.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                maths.setTitle("Maths");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WORKS " + maths, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.INFO, "Maths Clicked");
                return false;
            }
        });
        menuItemsAssigned = true;*/
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreateOptionsMenu()` there is this line:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu);
```

which apparently is wrong because it inflates the menu for the navigation drawer as the action bar menu. 
Replace `R.menu.navigation_menu` with the menu for the action bar.

Comment: But it will also change the menu for navigation drawer, won't it?

Comment: No it will not. This line inflates the menu for the actin bar. You do have 2 different menus in menu folder, right?

Comment: Yes I do have 2 But how is the menu for the drawer inflated?

Comment: By the name of it I suppose `R.menu.navigation_menu` is the menu of the NavigationDrawer and the other menu is for the action bar, right?

Comment: Yes R.menu.navigation_menu is for drawer/   I still don't get how the left side menu is inflated

Comment: You have set in NavigationView's xml: `app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"` so you don't need to change anything for it, but for the action bar menu you must set it by code in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:  `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_name, menu);`